# Why this class need to be abstract in scala?

Tags: scala

In java and c#,I can write this:

```
class Tree {
 Tree left;
 Tree right;
}
```

but in scala:

```
class Tree{
 val left:Tree
 val right:Tree
}
```

I need to add abstract for class,or write:

```
val left:Tree=new Tree()
```

I can write this:

```
trait Tree{
 val left:Tree
 val right:Tree
}
```

but why if I use class,I "have to"and abstract?I don't think it's a good design

Thanks!

Comment: So you have something abstract but do not want to define it as abstract?

Comment: @jwvh No, you do need to mark an abstract class as `abstract` in Java (and C# as far as I remember); the first class is not abstract because its fields are initialized to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because scala sometimes considers `val` and `def` as method like declarations. Let me elaborate, please, for instance, we have the next Scala example:

```
class Example {
  val a: String = "example"
}
val example = new Example()
println(example.a)
```

You may see that `a` declared as a field. Unlike Java, we can change this declaration easily to `def` and everything remains compiling:

```
class Example {
  def a: String = "example"
}
val example = new Example()
println(example.a)
```

In the case of Java (not sure about C# I've never worked with it), if you would like to access the field over getter method, you will need to change all invocation places from field to method access.

Now, you can consider `val` as let's say sort of eager cached `def` version - if so then declaring `val` without actually value assignment implicitly considered by compiler as declaring method without implementation and that's why compiler says `Tree` is an abstract class - because `left` and `right` has no values, hence they are abstract. In order to make it non-abstract, you need to assign a value to fields or use `var` if you would like to proceed with mutable structure, e.g.:

```
class Example {
  val a: String = "example"
}
val example = new Example()
println(example.a)
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bQIcVNk9SN6qJhbL32SMUQ

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can write

```
class Tree {
    Tree left;
    Tree right;
}
```

in Java and C# is because the fields are initialized to `null` by default (or to `0`, etc. depending on the type). Scala's designers decided this is a bad idea and you need to initialize them. So the approximate Scala equivalent is

```
class Tree {
  // note, not val
  var left: Tree = null
  var right: Tree = null
}
```

which is legal (but probably not something you actually want to use).

Answer (score 1):

> but why if I use class,I "have to"and abstract?

You have to mark your class with the `abstract` keyword because your class *is* abstract. It cannot possibly be instantiated.

> I don't think it's a good design

Good design is subjective. The designers of Scala thought that being explicit in this case, rather than making the class automatically abstract was good design. I would guess that the majority of the Scala community agrees with them.

You disagree, and that is perfectly okay.